# How add Flash support in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am implementing one web browser for my college mini project. It's showing all content
but it does not support Flash. It's not opening flash sites. How can I implement Flash support in `JEditorpane` of java swing?

Answer (score 2):

JEditorPane does not support flash. In fact, it has very limited html and css support too, so you can't implement a full blown browser using it.

Answer (score 2):

JEditorPane is fine for writing restricted browsers to be used for reading controlled HTML pages, like help-pages etc.

Today the most complete, 100% Java browser you can find is probably [The Lobo Project](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp). It is open-source and has an [API](http://lobobrowser.org/browser/api-info.jsp) that allows you to embed it in Swing applications well. **Lobo does not support Flash**, but allows you to use plug-ins, has a good support for CSS and allows you to study the code.

Answer (score 2):

Since `JEditorPane` doesn't support flash, you have to look for some alternatives if flash is a must. I do like to suggest the following project:

**[The DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net)**

It is a good solution to embed native components (web browser, flash player, etc.,) in to swing applications.  See the following links for extra info:

- [The DJ Project - Rediscover the Desktop](http://djproject.sourceforge.net)
- [Step-by-Step Instructions for Integrating DJ Native Swing into NetBeans RCP](http://netbeans.dzone.com/how-to-nb-djnative-swing)
- [Mixing Swing and Native Components](http://java.dzone.com/news/mixing-swing-and-native-compon)